# Why does Scala 3 fail to reduce an inline match over Either in this example?

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-3

Experimenting with Scala 3's metaprogramming capabilities, I found this issue with inline matching that I'm not able to satisfy myself with an explanation for.

Given a transparent inline method `eitherTest` which takes an inlined `Either[String, Int]` and then returns either the `String` or the `Int` directly using an inline match expression, things work perfectly fine if the input to `eitherTest` is explicitly typed to a `Left` or a `Right`. However, the compiler appears to be unable to reduce the match expression if the input is explicitly typed to the supertype of `Either`. What makes this more curious is that the argument to `eitherTest` is itself typed as `Either`.

Is this a compiler bug? Is this expected behavior? I'm struggling to understand why the compiler would not be able to resolve this.

Scastie link: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/CThqajauRVeJvxvW0uYy4w

Code:

```
@main def hello: Unit =
  workingTest
  failingTest


def workingTest: Unit =
  val l: Left[String, Int] = Left("hello")
  val r: Right[String, Int] = Right(22)
  val tl: String = eitherTest(l)
  val tr: Int = eitherTest(r)
  println(s"$tl :: $tr")

def failingTest: Unit =
  val l: Either[String, Int] = Left("hello")
  val r: Either[String, Int] = Right(22)
  val tl: String = eitherTest(l)
  val tr: Int = eitherTest(r)
  println(s"$tl :: $tr")

transparent inline def eitherTest(inline v: Either[String, Int]): Any =
  inline v match
    case Right(a) => a
    case Left(b) => b
```

Error:

```
cannot reduce inline match with
 scrutinee:  l : (l : Either[String, Int])
 patterns :  case Right.unapply[String, Int](a @ _):Right[String, Int]
             case Left.unapply[String, Int](b @ _):Left[String, Int]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  val l: Either[String, Int] = Left("hello")
  val r: Either[String, Int] = Right(22)
```

This explicitly discards type information, leaving the compiler unable to infer what it needs. I believe the `transparent` relies on type knowledge of passed arguments, rather than "dark type magic" around statically defined values. If you erase the type of the passed arguments, then it is fair to fail right?

Comment: Agree. If at compile time something is only known to be an `Either` — and that's what upcasting does — neither case is known to apply. And if neither case applies, the compiler is right to complain; there’s nothing it can reasonably do